# How to copy datasets from prior version directory to latest version directory

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I've go a number of directories named like:

```
/data/db/OX/8_10
/data/db/OX/9_1
/data/db/OX/9_2
```

And need to copy some files (all the `pt.*` files) from the second latest one (above `9_1`) to the latest one (above `9_2`).

I have tried directly like this.

```
cp -p /data/db/OX/9_1/pt.*  /data/db/OX/9_2
```

However, Instead of typing /data/db/OX/9_1/   & /data/db/OX/9_2. I'd like to be able to write:

```
cp -p /data/db/OS/"$prior_version"/pt.* /data/db/OS/"$latest_version"/
```

And derive `$prior_version` and `$latest_version` from the list of directories in `/data/db/OX/` in a shell script.

Comment: Do you have any plans for asking a question in the future which doesn't get deleted? Shall we guess what "automatically" is supposed to mean?

Comment: Other readers, please see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74882/how-to-copy-datasets-automaticaly and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74557/how-to-pick-higer-version-directory-automatically-and-make-directory-on-that-hig and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74885/how-to-copy-sas-files-from-prior-version-directory-to-new-version-directory

Answer (score 1):

With the `zsh` shell, you could do:

```
cd /data/db/OX || exit
latest_two=(<->_<->(N/nOn[1,2])
(($#latest_two == 2)) || exit
cp -p $latest_two[2]/pt.* $latest_two[1]/
```

POSIXly assuming filenames don't contain newline characters:

```
cd /data/db/OX || exit
set -- $(ls -F |
  grep -xE '[0-9]+_[0-9]+/' |
  sort -rnt _ -k 1,1 -k 2,2 |
  head  -n 2)
[ "$#" -eq 2 ] || exit
cp -p "$2"pt.* "$1"
```

Both do the same:

1. They get the list of directories that look like `number_number`
2. Sort them reverse-numerically (nOn, sort -rn)
3. pick the first two
4. copy `pt.*` files from the second to the first.

Comment: Not working for this script.

Comment: @jos *What* is not working? Does it copy the wrong files? Does it cause your computer to burst into flames?